# A navigator can only contain 'Screen', 'Group' or 'React.Fragment' as its direct children

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  {
    isLogin ? <ComponentA /> :  <ComponentB />
  }
</Stack.Navigator>


const ComponentA = () => (
 arrA.map( v => <Stack.Screen name={v.name} component={v.component} />)
)

const ComponentB = () => (
 arrB.map( v => <Stack.Screen name={v.name} component={v.component} />)
)
```

i want use some hooks in componentA and componentB, so i have to use them as function component, any help please?

[source code](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/1179d56c5008270753feef41acdc1dbd2191efcf/packages/core/src/useNavigationBuilder.tsx#L104)

Answer (score 5):

An option could be to render the components inline:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  {
    isLogin ? ComponentA({}) :  ComponentB({})
  }
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: Life Saver! i was using this which caused issue.
<Stack.Navigator>
  {
    isLogin && ComponentA({})
  }
</Stack.Navigator>

Answer (score 1):

I think this is could be a bug for `react-navigation` but i found a solution to fix the error.

**Solution:**

1. Remove the `Stack.Screen` that caused the problem from `Stack.Navigator`
2. Then `copy` and `paste` last `Stack.Screen` item in your `Stack.Navigator`
3. Change the `name` and `component` props to your new screen but **don't save** the changes
4. Restart `metro server` and emulator
5. run your project and you will see error no more existed.

Comment: Thank you, simply restarting the metro server solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? Please elaborate.

Anyway, I think a general direction would be:

```
const componentA = props => {
// Whatever you wanna do

return (<>
{arrA.map( v => <Stack.Screen name={v.name} component={v.component} />)}
</>)

}
```

Same for `componentB`

Comment: i have try this solution, it does not work, the same error

Comment: Then try something like
`<Stack.Navigator>
<>
  {
    isLogin ? <ComponentA /> :  <ComponentB />
  }
</>
</Stack.Navigator>`

Comment: no it does not work, [source code](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/1179d56c5008270753feef41acdc1dbd2191efcf/packages/core/src/useNavigationBuilder.tsx#L104) here,  any help ?

Comment: put the `<Stack.Screen>` directly into the `<Stack.Navigator>`, you still can use hooks after

Comment: @VáclavRyska  i just wanna use hooks inside ComponentA and ComponentB, that is because when isLogin changes, states can be reset in ComponentA or ComponentB.

Answer (score -1):

**1. Make sure you have installed '@react-navigation/native' and '@react-navigation/stack'.**

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
npm install @react-navigation/stack
```

**2. Make sure to have react-navigation properly sat up:**

*On iOS:*

```
cd ios
pod install
```

*On Android:*
Locate this file: `android/app/build.gradle` and add the following under `dependencies`

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

**3. Try to restart Metro and Emulator (in the terminal, just use Ctrl + C or Cmd + C). Then try to restart it again.**

```
npx react-native start // running metro
npx react-native run-android // running the android emulator, replace `run-android` with `run-ios`, if you want to use the iOS simulator.
```